How do Lix channels compare with Nix channels?
With Nix, you have channels such as 23.11 (latest stable) and unstable, with the stable channel offering relatively old package versions, and the unstable channel offering relatively new versions.
You can also browse a list of older versions, and choose to install a particular version by hash.
How does Lix work in this respect? Are there various channels, or only one stable channel at this point? How does the Lix stable channel compare to the Nix stable channel, as regards newness of packages?
Can you browse a list of older versions, and install one by hash?
While we are on the subject, how do you even browse the Lix package list? Is there an equivalent of https://search.nixos.org/packages ?
I did not discover a website with Lix packages.
